# Find src attributes with at least 10 characters

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have working `preg_match_all` which finds all images from website and gets `src`. My question is how I can check if the `$matches` have more than 10 characters

My current code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.everypixel.com/search?q=italy&is_id=1&st=free');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $html, $matches);

if (sizeof($matches[1]) >= 10) {
  // something
}
```

Just need to replace `if (sizeof($matches[1]) >= 10) {` into something that will check it in `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex or other direct string approaches aren't good tools to parse html. PHP has many classes designed for that: `DOMDocument`, `DOMXPath`, `DOMWhatEverYouWant`. You have to learn how to use these classes and how to manipulate the DOM.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.everypixel.com/search?q=italy&is_id=1&st=free');
$html = curl_exec($ch);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = $xp->query('//img/@src[string-length(.)>9]');

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->nodeValue, "<br>";
}
```

Comment: DOMWhatEverYouWant sounds like a very powerful library :) The opposite of simple-html-dom

Comment: @Barmar: It's my favourite!

Answer (score 0):

There is the way to set minimum and unlimited maximum needed characters in regular expression. {10,} means from minimum 10 and no limit applying to this rule [^\'"]

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.everypixel.com/search?q=italy&is_id=1&st=free');
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src=[\'"]?([^\'"\s]{10,})/i', $html, $matches);
// All search lines are in $matches[1]
```

Comment: What if the src attribute value isn't quoted at all?

Comment: Thanks, added \s to stop chars [^\'"\s]